# Trying to make reusable code, using the function parameter to fill in the areas of the variable named target

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters, parameter-passing, code-reuse

Trying to make reusable code, using the function parameter to fill in the areas of the variable named target.  Im not even sure if I can use it in this manner.

Working:

```
function loadBtn() {
    sizeOfPartnersList = $("#partners div.partner-wrapper").size();
    x=4;
    $('#partners div.partner-wrapper:lt('+x+')').css('display', 'table');
    $('.load-more-btn').click(function () {
        x= (x+4 <= sizeOfPartnersList) ? x+4 : sizeOfPartnersList;
        $('#partners div.partner-wrapper:lt('+x+')').css('display', 'table');

        var numberOfVisiblePartners = $('div.partner-wrapper:visible').size();

        if ( numberOfVisiblePartners ===  $("#partners div.partner-wrapper").size()) {
            $('.load-more-btn').hide();
        };
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    loadBtn();
});
```

Not Working:

```
function loadBtn(target) {

    // target = target;
    sizeOfPartnersList = $("#partners div." + target).size();
    x=4;
    $('#partners div.'+ target ':lt('+x+')').css('display', 'table');
    $('.load-more-btn').click(function () {
        console.log('loading-02');
        x= (x+4 <= sizeOfPartnersList) ? x+4 : sizeOfPartnersList;
        $('#partners div.'+ target ':lt('+x+')').css('display', 'table');

        var numberOfVisiblePartners = $('div.'+ target ':visible').size();

        if ( numberOfVisiblePartners ===  $("#partners div." + target).size()) {
            $('.load-more-btn').hide();
        };
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    loadBtn('partner-wrapper');
});
```

Comment: For all the questions you've asked on this site, please have a look here: [What to do when an answer solved my problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2):

There are some errors in the strings, you always need to use `+` when you are concatenating strings and variables.

```
$('#partners div.'+ target ':lt('+x+')')
```

should be

```
$('#partners div.'+ target +':lt('+x+')')
```

Same here:

```
$('#partners div.'+ target ':lt('+x+')').css('display', 'table');

var numberOfVisiblePartners = $('div.'+ target ':visible').size();
```

Change to:

```
$('#partners div.'+ target +':lt('+x+')').css('display', 'table');

var numberOfVisiblePartners = $('div.'+ target +':visible').size();
```

Note the added `+` after `target` in each line.

Full code:

```
function loadBtn(target) {
    sizeOfPartnersList = $("#partners div." + target).size();
    x=4;
    $('#partners div.'+ target +':lt('+x+')').css('display', 'table');
    $('.load-more-btn').click(function () {
        console.log('loading-02');
        x= (x+4 <= sizeOfPartnersList) ? x+4 : sizeOfPartnersList;
        $('#partners div.'+ target +':lt('+x+')').css('display', 'table');

        var numberOfVisiblePartners = $('div.'+ target +':visible').size();

        if ( numberOfVisiblePartners ===  $("#partners div." + target).size()) {
            $('.load-more-btn').hide();
        };
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    loadBtn('partner-wrapper');
});
```